# Bitcoind walletnotify

Tags: bitcoind, litecoin, wallet-notify

Does wallet notify performs actions also on old transactions? In case that my node went offline for some reason, Once its back online I will get notifications from wallet notify for the transactions that I missed when it was offline or not?

Tnx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It will send a notification once a transaction added to your bitcoin core wallet. so, when you start your node again any transactions belongs to your wallet you should get a notification for.

```
-walletnotify=<cmd> Execute command when a wallet transaction changes (%s in cmd is replaced by TxID)
```